# Where does Quran or authentic hadith say that women have to cover everything except face, hands and feet?

Tags: tafseer, hadith-interpretation, hijab, surat-an-noor

My question is from [this short video lecture](https://ms.jaag.pk/cont/v/sd/5/5c0e1b741eb2ed7b0002e797.mp4).

He summarizes the concept of pardah/hijab/covering in 3 points.
a. Surah Noor - Lower your gaze for both men and women, i.e. look at opposite sex with respect and dignity.
b. Safeguard your *sharamgaah* for both men and women.
c. Ocassionally when women are wearing ornaments and make up etc, then women have to cover everything except face, hands and feet.

1. **Question from Point b above:**

What is the Quranic verse which tells us to safeguard the sharamgaah? Essentially, what specific Arabic word is used for sharamgaah, and does that word only mean genitals?

2. **Questions from Point c above:**

(2a) What is the source of this instruction to cover everything except face, hands and feet in case of make-up and ornaments? Where exactly is it said in Quran or authentic Hadith?

(2b) I go for *no-make-up makeup look* for my office everything, which is very little make-up applied in colors close to skin-tone, so that face just looks fresh and awake (and not sick). Does it make me qualified for point c above?

Comment: There are two orthodox positions, (1) women must cover everything or (2) they must cover everything except face, hands (and some add feet). Having ornaments on does not make a difference in either one. I suspect that the position you are talking about is held by no one except individuals who maybe try to offer their own understanding of the Quran.

Comment: @UmH Thank you for your comment. I want to know the source (from Quran or authentic Hadith) on which the (1) and (2) orthodox positions you're talking about are based.