# Where can I find all Bukari and Muslim hadith related to hijab of women?

Tags: hadith, hijab, sahih-bukhari, sahih-muslim

Is there a collection of all Sahih-Bukhari and Sahih-Muslim hadith about hijab/covering of women? I didn't get clear answers to [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71802/where-does-quran-or-authentic-hadith-say-that-women-have-to-cover-everything-exc), so I was looking for a place where all authentic hadith related to the subject would be, so that I could study myself?

Answer (score 1):

**A short info on the compilation of both Sahih's**

Each author of hadith compilations has compiled the ahadith he relies on in different  chapters, some or maybe even most of these authors might have compiled the same hadith (content) in different chapters based on the related topics. Among those authors al-Bukhari is certainly the one with the most authentic ahadith compilation. Imam Muslim mainly has chosen to further support the more authentic narrations he had at hand with other authentic ones (either by fully quoting them or by only quoting deviations in the narrator chain or content) in the same chapter. However Sahih Muslims originally was a book of 54 "head chapters" the subsection titles and order as we commonly know today are the creation of imam an-Nawawi, as imam Muslim left these details out, other commentators of Sahih Muslim have chosen other titles, orders and selections of the hadith of a "head chapter".
Others might have chosen to avoid duplicates and might have quoted a hadith only once in their book.

**Re-phrased question**

Having this said I can answer your question based on the following re-phrased version:

> "Is there a chapter in Sahih-Bukhari and Sahih-Muslim where I can find all ahadith about hijab/covering of women?"

### Both Sahih books have chapters on the topic of clothing

So if you check [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari) you will find "The book of [Clothes and Adornment](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77)" this is the head chapter to look inside here.
As for [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim) the corresponding chapter is "The book of [Clothes and adornment](https://sunnah.com/muslim/37)".

### None of both Sahih's addresses the "hijab" as a specific topic

However you won't find them mentioning hijab itself, but the focus of the corresponding chapters in both books is more on:

- the order of covering the 'awrah:
  for example the prohibition of nudity (see [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim:341) in Sahih Muslim, *but in a different chapter*) or
  inappropriate clothes which are disclosing (see in Sahih Muslim [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2128)) or
  the prohibition to look at the 'awrah of others be it from the same sex or different genders (see [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim:338a) in Sahih Muslim, *but in a different chapter*) or
- the prohibition to do alike the non-Muslims (generally and in the context of clothing especially (see [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2069c) in Sahih Muslim and [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5892) in Sahih al-Bukhari)
- the prohibition for women to act or wear like men (see in Sahih al-Bukhari [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5885), [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5886) and [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5887))

### Hijab was ordered by the qur'an

Before leaving the impression that both authors of Sahih hadith, didn't consider hijab as obligatory and only mentioned narrations about "appropriate clothing" in their books.
We must check the entire book and we will find that they refer to the qur'an as the revelation which ordered "hijab" in different ahadith -in the following I'll only share a few, but not all of them-:
In Sahih al-Bukhari in the book of Tafsir when quoting ahadith on the verse ([33:53](https://legacy.quran.com/33/53)) [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4790), [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4791) [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4792) and in the following ahadith and elsewhere. Al-Bukhari also quoted in his Sahih [this](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4758) hadith -which was also compiled by abu Dawod (see later)- when addressing the Tafisr of the verse ([24:31](https://legacy.quran.com/24/31)) which make clear how the Sahabi women () understood and interpreted this verse.
Imam Muslim quoted ahadith referring to the revelation of the verse on hijab [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2170d) and [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2396) and elsewhere in the book.

### Other sources go more in details

Most ahadith on the hijab which you may find are however covered in other hadith compilations like the Sunan Books of abu Dawod, ibn Majah an-Nasa-i and Jami' at-Tirmidhi or the Musnad of imam Ahmad and other compilations like Sahih ibn Hebban etc. most of these ahadith have a good level of authenticity, but among them are also weak ahadith. Nevertheless scholars may differ in their qualifications.
Among the rather known ahadith in this regards are:

- > When Surat an-Nur came down, they took the curtains, tore them and made head covers (veils) of them. ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4100))
- > Asma, daughter of AbuBakr, entered upon the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) wearing thin clothes. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) turned his attention from her. He said: O Asma', when a woman reaches the age of menstruation, it does not suit her that she displays her parts of body except this and this, and he pointed to his face and hands. ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4104))